# How to stop '%3F', '%26', '%3d' from getting generated in between of string?

Tags: android, uri

The code below:

```
Uri BASE_URL = Uri.parse("http://www.appname.com/");
APP_URI = BASE_URL.buildUpon().path(imageUIDh).build();
```

is generating symbols like: `'%3F'`, `'%26'` in between of string.

The string `imageUIDh` was supposed to be: `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/appname-e2a34.appspot.com/o/79687?alt=media&token=82ebd9ec-da19-4fef-ba68-e4015a47ad5e` but is getting changed into `https%3A//firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/appname-e2a34.appspot.com/o/79687%3Falt%3Dmedia%26token%3D82ebd9ec-da19-4fef-ba68-e4015a47ad5e`

Why is this happening and how to avoid this from happening or how to remove them?

Please let me know.

Comment: https://perishablepress.com/url-character-codes/, '%3F' its your "?" ,  when you the already encoded url gets encoded again which leads to this behavior

Comment: @HenningLuther How to avoid this?